# SQL REGEX WHERE COLUMN = 'VALUES' PARSER

Tags: c#, java, .net, sql, regex

I'm making a regex to match all value inside the column = **'value'** mainly on the sql's where clause the value can be from alphanumeric to special char, space, ', = etc.
Here's what I have so far.

SQL:

> select count(*) from t_cusUser where AccountID = '`!@#$%^&()+{}?|.'_' 
>   and column = '3' and column = '`~!@#$%^&-_+{}|'./?Polite'

REGEX:

> (?<=\=)\s?N?\'([\w\'-\s\&{}#\$\^()\@\~\%\|/.`*\~!+\?"]+)\'

RESULT:

1. '`!@#$%^&()+{}?|.'_'
2. '3'
3. '`~!@#$%^&-_+{}|'./?Polite'

It works fine, but if I put a **=** character then the problem occurs.

REGEX: (Added = char)

> (?<=\=)\s?N?\'([\w\'-\s\&{}#\$\^()\@\~\%\|/.`*\~!+\?"**=**]+)\'

RESULT:

1. '`!@#$%^&*()+{}?|.'_'  and column = '3'  and column = '`~!@#$%^&*-_+{}|'./?Polite'

Comment: Shouldn't your `'` be escaped in your values?

Comment: Have you tried using `\=`instead of `=`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

((?<=\=)\s*N?[a-zA-Z0-9.!?#$=@&%'^+|_~-/()*{}`]+)'